# In a matrix, link to entries with a future date

Tags: matrix, entry, datetime

This is somewhat related to this [How can I display a "pending" entry in my "_entry" template?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1639/how-can-i-display-a-pending-entry-in-my-entry-template)

I have an 'events' section where some entries have a future date - the above link solved my issue to get those listed in a sidebar and display single entries while ignoring the date. So far so good.

I have a homepage slider (a matrix field) where each slide can link to an entry - problem is those entries with a future date from the 'events' section are simply not showing up.(block.slideLink is my entries field inside the matrix)

Any ideas how to get around this?

```
{% for block in entry.homeslider %}
    {% if block.type == 'slides' %}         
        <div class="item {% if loop.first %}active{% endif %}">
        <img src="{{ siteUrl }}assets/img/slide-1.jpg" alt="" />
            <div class="k-carousel-caption pos-2-3-right scheme-dark">
                <div class="caption-content">
                    <h3 class="caption-title">{{ block.slideTitle }}</h3>
                    <p>{{ block.slideIntro }}</p>
                    <p>
                        {% for link in block.slideLink %}
                        <a href="{{ link.url }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">lees verder...</a>                                               
                        {% endfor %}
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Forgot to take the entry status into account + an additional check for the sectionhandle to cover the custom route.
This solved it for me, if you have a better suggestion I'm all ears.

```
{% for link in block.slideLink.status('live', 'pending') %}
    {% if link.section.handle == 'events' %}
        <a href="{{ siteUrl }}events/{{ link.slug }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">lees verder...</a> 
    {% else %}
        <a href="{{ link.url }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">lees verder...</a> 
    {% endif %} 
{% endfor %}
```