# How to Generate Unique Slugs for a Section without ticking "Entries in this section have their own URLs"

Tags: entries, slug

I am working on a site that has an events calendar with Future, Current and Expired events being shown. Which is completely fine when I am on the index page and have "Entries in this section have their own URLs" checked for that section. The problem I run into then is that the permalink page will only show entries that the are live. Pending and Expired entries will never be shown (As mentioned in [this](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/8480/how-do-i-set-up-event-listing-detail-pages-with-entry-post-dates-that-are-in-t) questions and answer).

We have a lot of events that have similar or the same name that happen on a weekly or monthly basis. For example "Live Music at Blue Skies Winery" produces a slug of "ive-music-at-blue-skies-winery" when I had Entries in this section have their own URLs it would increment the slug like `live-music-at-blue-skies-winery1` and the next one would be `live-music-at-blue-skies-winery2`.

So as a result I have disabled it for my event section but as a result now entries with the same title have the same slug of `live-music-at-blue-skies-winery` without being incremented.

Is there a way to force the slugs to be unique either by incrementing the slug like happens when I have Entries in this section have their own URLs checked or is it possible to prepend the entry date 03-01-2015 to the slug name?

Comment: Check out [this question](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/1639/45) as well...

Comment: Thanks Lindsey that is actually what I ended up doing because I really didn't want to go through and edit all of My existing entries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably just set your event dates using custom Date/Time fields rather than the Post Date and Expiration Date fields. That way you don’t have to fight with Craft’s restrictions on non-live entries.